# library for sending trackbacks / pingbacks in php

Tags: trackback

I am writing my own blog system. Is there a library for sending trackbacks / pingbacks or a good example how to do this? I played with xmlrpc and the post method but without success. I need a working class, I would also pay for the script, any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might come too late, but I actually asked myself the exact same question a while ago. I did not find a good library, so instead wrote my own. I've put up a repository at https://github.com/tedeh/pingback-php

It should be pretty straight forward.